# Mongoose - store multiple model types in one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema which looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamps');

const BidSchema = new Schema({
  bidder: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Buyer'
  },
  counterOffer: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Counter_Offer'
  },
  box: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Box'
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Disapproved']
  },
  bidPrice: Number,
  bidTimeout: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isAnonymous: Boolean,
});

BidSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bid', BidSchema);
```

I want to store multiple data types in the `Box` field. For example, I have a `Box` model and also I have a `GroupedBox` model. I want to be able to store id for both of these schemas and to be able to populate this field accordingly. For instance, if the document will store an ObjectId that references a `GroupedBox` document, the populate method will fetch the right `GroupedBox` document. Same goes for a `Box` document id.

I read about `Mixed` field types but I don't see how that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

replace `box` field in your code with this:

```
box: {
     box: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Box' },
     groupedBox : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'GroupedBox' }
}
```

To populate `box` you need to access box with a dot `populate("box.box")` similar to `groupedBox` you populate it this way `populate("box.groupedBox")`